# Linear Combination of regression model of relative independent and dependent variables

Tags: regression, least-squares, z-score

I would like to check, if I run into a **linear combination issue** regarding the following regression model:

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1Z(\frac{a_i - b_i}{a_i}) - \beta_2Z(\frac{b_i - c_i}{b_i}) +  \epsilon_i $

$y_i$ is defined as $\frac{a_i - c_i}{a_i}$
and
$Z$ is the Z-transformation ($\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$).

The dependent variable ($y_i$) is clearly dependent on some independent variables ($a_i$ and $c_i$), however, I wonder whether 1) the relative definition of independent variables (e.g., $\frac{a_i - b_i}{a_i}$), 2) the absence of $b_i$ in the dependent variable and/or 3) the Z-transformation are valid measures to avoid the problem of linear combination in this regression model.

Comment: Hi: you've got $b_i$ in both variables ( the ones with $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$) which makes them dependent. you can have RHS variables that are dependent but how much is what matters.